# How can I have a custom Pages page size?

Tags: pages

I'm trying to select, in the Documents tab, an A2 paper size so that it represents better the information that I will be printing out. However, there is no A2 paper size. I am also aware that under the Printing dialog (Paper Handling), there are more document types, but still no A2 size.

Therefore, is there a way to make Pages visualise a custom paper size inside a document, and if yes, what is it?

Specs for reference: MacBook Pro (Retina, Early 2015) running OS X El Capitan v10.11.4 and Pages v5.6.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using custom paper sizes actually falls to the printer driver, via the Page Setup window.

1. In Pages, select "Page Setup" from the File menu.
2. Click the "Paper Size" menu, and way at the bottom, select "Manage Custom Sizes".
3. This will present a window where you can define your page dimensions, give it a name, and save it for future use in the Page Setup window. (see screenshot)

   [image: Custom Page Size Window]
4. Once you've defined your paper size, it will always appear in the Page Setup window in the Paper Size dropdown menu, and Pages will use that size once selected.

Comment: This is great. Thank you! I tried to create an A5-Borderless option (simply A5 without margins) and Pages won't allow it. After closing the dialogue window, when i reopen it, the old setting (normal A5) is selected. I am wondering why?

Comment: All printers have minimal margins, and it will default back to those margins for the printer you have selected. You cannot go completely borderless.